# ImageResizer rotation issues

Tags: imageresizer

I rotated a few images on my computer, however, image resizer keeps using the old orientation. When I navigate to the image just using the image path, it shows up fine. However, when I add ?h=400, it's using the old orientation. What's causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application you are using to rotate images is only setting the Exif Orientation metadata flag. ImageResizer will honor aforementioned metadata if you install the [Autorotate plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/autorotate) and specify &autorotate=true in the command string.

Browser and mail reader support for Exif Orientation is extremely spotty; I'm surprised your browser actually rotated the image.

Keep in mind that rotation is somewhat expensive; it's good to have your images *actually* rotated ahead of time, as it will make images render consistently and a bit faster (especially on mobile or slow connections).

ImageResizer does not output the `exif orientation` flag, it always produces a *true* rotated image.

Comment: I rotated right in Windows Explorer using a right click. I opened my imaged in an actual image editing app and resaved it. That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ImageResizer is now able to rotate without the plugin. Just add `&autorotate=true` to the URL.

See: https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/reference