# How to prevent ImageResizer from flipping portrait images?

Tags: imageresizer

I am using the free version of ImageResizer to process uploaded jpeg files. Prior to version 4, these commands worked flawlessly, constraining the images with the proper rotation and aspect ratio:

versions.Add("_medium", "maxwidth=1800&maxheight=1800&format=jpg")

Now, all the portrait images are flipping to landscape (horizontal). I have tried all the commands -- flip, sflip, rotate, etc. and nothing helps. Most of the images being uploaded are scans, so there would be no camera information complicating matters.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanners still add exif rotation data. Please share your diagnostics page so we can see what you are doing.

Typically you would add `&autorate=true` or set it globally:         `<pipeline defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true" />`

Please see:

- [How to use the autorotate plugin in ImageResizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700695/how-to-use-the-autorotate-plugin-in-imageresizer)
- [ImageResizer rotation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631063/imageresizer-rotation-issues/25653030#25653030)
- [why does ImageResizer is rotating automaticlly image photographed vertical and show it horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983705/why-does-imageresizer-is-rotating-automaticlly-image-photographed-vertical-and-s)

Comment: Thanks very much. Autorotate=true seems to be doing the trick. It's a wonderful app.